# How to dynamically populate a template from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I'm trying to finalize a web dev project for one of my college courses. My partner and I took it upon ourselves to use the IGDB API. We currently have a JSON object and a HTML template of how I want the page to look. Do I need to create a Javascript function to populate the appropriate items? Do I pass the values from the JSON object to the HTML page? Web development really isn't my strong point and I feel like I'm asking the wrong questions when I search online.

Current use case:
1. A user searches for a video game using a search bar/button.
2. The website returns a list of video game images/title
3. User clicks on the  tag for a given game
4. // Create page from given game's information in the JSON object

This is where we are stuck, and I don't know what question I need to ask. I've played around with the idea of doing it all via document.createElement, but I feel like that is silly. We currently have the JSON object in our server.js file and our instructor hinted at creating the page there, and not in another Javascript file. He also suggested using express/angular, but I have no idea where to start with those languages.

Comment: I saw that you already have been in StackOverflow asking, but not replied nor accepted any of the answer people gave to you. Think that people is taking their time to answer you so be considerate and at least be a bit grateful by upvoting or accepting the answers. Don't be that selfish please.

Answer (score 0):

express and angular are not languages (Google a bit, pls xD).

express is just an HTTP server, and angular is a framework that runs on the client to help you create webpages, specifically SPAs. Everything in JavaScript language.

This question is too broad so might be closed, but I'm trying to throw you a bit of light. This was going to be a comment but got a bit long so I wrote it as an answer.

There's nothing wrong by creating elements dynamically with `document.createElement`. That's how angular works actually (and almost all modern webpages). The thing is to have the entire app correctly designed (HINT: MVC). You can try angular/react/vue.js as *they will create elements for you* depending on your application state (which you can modify after loading and processing the JSON data). Each framework has its pros and cons. You should do a lot of research on your own before electing one.

The key here is to have knowledge of basic JavaScript, specifically about callbacks as I've seen a lot of problems from newbies coming from this side.

**PROTIP**: To start with `something`, just open Google, ask abut that `something` and read. Read a lot (a fkn lot).

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped clear up some things for me. I really feel over my head and my instructor skipped right over the basics and started recommending things to try and I didn't know where to begin.

Comment: @DaltonSchnieders Nice ^^